# Omnifaces 2.6.8 and Myfaces 2.3.0

Tags: myfaces, apache-tomee, omnifaces

I'm trying to upgrade myfaces to latest version (without the whole java EE 8 stack, since tomee 8 is still not released).

It seems to work fine in most of the cases, however refreshing some pages throws this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Integer
at org.omnifaces.util.Hacks.removeViewState(Hacks.java:432)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.unloadView(OmniViewHandler.java:134)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.restoreView(OmniViewHandler.java:101)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:97)
```

**Please note that this is not a bug report, it's just a question**. Should omnifaces 2.x work with jsf 2.3?

Comment: BTW, it has something to do with omnifaces @ViewScoped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by unload of a page associated with OmniFaces `@ViewScoped`. This is supposed to work just fine. This issue also manifests in OmniFaces 3.0. It has as per [issue 444](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/444) been fixed in OmniFaces 2.6.9 and 3.1.